# How to make buttons text get different directions animation in android studio

Tags: android

I want to bring the text of the buttons from different directions.
I looked at the ObjectAnimatore but couldn't.

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(altbutonlar.get(i), "textColor", Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    colorAnim.setDuration(100);
                    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                    colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
                    colorAnim.start();
```

Comment: do you want to move text with an animation ?

Comment: Yes i want to button text bring with animation.

Comment: you can create a textView inside a FrameLayout layout and set the style to make the frameLayout like a Button and you can animate the textView

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure you have a look at [ask] and how to produce a [mre]. You don't seem to have told us in the question what the issue with your code is, what trouble you had fixing it etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a TextView inside a FrameLayout and set the style so that the FrameLayout looks like a Button and you can animate the TextView like you want.

Here is an example of what i'm talking about

in the Layout use FrameLayout like this :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolBar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is how I animate the TextView in the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private FrameLayout buttonContainer;

    private static final int DIRECTION_L = -1;
    private static final int DIRECTION_R = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonContainer = findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer);
        buttonContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> animate(DIRECTION_L, DIRECTION_R, "Hello world"));

    }

    /**
     * @param directionOut direction out -1 from left or 1 from right
     * @param directionIn  direction in -1 from left or 1 from right
     * @param newText  the new text you want to added in textView
     */

    private void animate(int directionOut, int directionIn, String newText) {
        int lastPosition = buttonContainer.getWidth() / 2 + textView.getWidth() / 2;// get the position x to TextView inside frameLayout
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "TranslationX", 0, directionOut * lastPosition);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.5f));
        animator.setDuration(600);
        animator.start();

        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                addNewText(directionIn, newText);
                animation.removeAllListeners();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * if you want to add new new text that slide In
     *
     * @param directionIn -1 from left or 1 from right
     * @param newText     the new text you want to added in textView
     */
    private void addNewText(int directionIn, String newText) {
        textView.setText(newText);
        int lastPosition = buttonContainer.getWidth() / 2 + textView.getWidth() / 2;// get the position x to TextView inside frameLayout
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "TranslationX", directionIn * lastPosition, 0);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.5f));
        animator.setDuration(600);
        animator.start();
    }

}
```

And this is how the result looks:

[image]